# Spring security configuration with angular served by backend

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm building a webapp with angular for the front and java for the backend (stack spring-boot, spring security, jwt, ...)
I'm a little confused about how things should work together.

**In dev mode, it works fine :**

I have proxified my backend api call with something like below

**proxy.conf.js**

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [{
    context: [
        "/api"
    ],
    target: "http://localhost:8080",
    secure: false
}]

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

and setup the spring security configuration like this

```
    ...

    private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
        "/signup",
        "/h2-console/*",
        "/login",
        "/api/public/**",
        "/error",};

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .headers().frameOptions().disable()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST)
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

**For production mode, I would like the backend to serve the api and frontend generated by angular in one jar and be able to start my webapp like this :**

```
java -jar myWebapp.jar
```

Let me show you my pom files

**frontend module pom.xml :**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    
...
    
    <!-- Build -->
    <build>
        
        <!-- Resources -->
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>./dist</directory>
                <targetPath>static</targetPath>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        
        <!-- Plugin --> 
        <plugins>
            
            <!-- Maven frontend plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.10.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <workingDirectory>./</workingDirectory>
                    <nodeVersion>v12.16.1</nodeVersion>
                    <npmVersion>6.14.5</npmVersion>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm run build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**backend module pom.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    ...    

    <!-- Build -->
    <build>        
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources-frontend</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/static/</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${basedir}/../frontend/dist/</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    
</project>
```

**The question :**
Now, my backend serve the api and the static content generated by angular.

I have 4 types of query :

- /api/private/** => Only if authenticated
- /api/public/** => Everyone
- any static resources like index.html or logo.png =>  Everyone
- /dashboard or /profile => route angular which should be allowed by spring security and will be handled by angular router

How should I update my spring security configuration for not blocking the static content ? Is it safe to setup spring security with permitAll on /** except for /api/private/** (which should be authenticated) so all static content is availlable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add multiple antmachers

```
.antMatchers("/").permitAll()  //root level
.antMatchers("/api/public/**,/index.html**").permitAll()
```

Adding **/**** in antMatchers will allow the user to access everything.
Other urls which don't match will be automatically handled by spring security for authentication